CefSharp.Offline.NetCore in a .NET 8.0 gRPC Service errors out on Cef.Initialize()
I have a .NET 6.0 gRPC service that is called from various clients to take screenshots of webpages. I am using CefSharp.Offline.NetCore to do the job. Things work great when the Target Framework of the project is set to 6.0. However, 6.0 is "going away" at the end of 2024, so I need to update the project to .NET 8.0.
When I set the project's Target Framework to .NET 8.0, CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe crashes after a few seconds. The gRPC debug/console window shows (there are a ~half dozen of those before the "Goodbye."):
[35580:4120:0626/103428.643:ERROR:network_service_instance_impl.cc(600)] Network service crashed, restarting service.
[35580:4120:0626/103429.036:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1002)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=-532462766
[35580:4120:0626/103429.036:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(449)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.

The Windows Application log shows:
Application: CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe
CoreCLR Version: 4.700.22.55902
.NET Core Version: 3.1.32
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(QCallAssembly assembly, String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ObjectHandleOnStack type, ObjectHandleOnStack keepAlive, ObjectHandleOnStack assemblyLoadContext)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError)
   at System.StartupHookProvider.CallStartupHook(StartupHookNameOrPath startupHook)
   at System.StartupHookProvider.ProcessStartupHooks()

I have the latest x86/x64 runtimes installed as of 6-26-2024. I am using CefSharp 126.2.70.
My initialization looks like:
var settings = new CefSettings()
{
    LogFile = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "Debug.log", //You can customise this path
    LogSeverity = LogSeverity.Default 
};

Cef.Initialize(settings, performDependencyCheck: true, browserProcessHandler: null);

I've tried disabling the GPU with:
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu", "1");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu-vsync", "1");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu-compositing", "1");

to no avail. Any ideas?

I have almost this exact same problem. I've been running a .NET 7 project with no issues, and then today I started getting this exact problem despite no (apparent) code changes.

Using your own exe instead of the provided one when targeting .Net Core is generally what it'd recommend. The provided exe is build with .Net core 3.1 as it's too hard to provide a different exe for each version. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/SelfHost-BrowserSubProcess
